# Stream data with Stomp over Websockets to Grafana

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, grafana, stomp

I see a Websockets plugin available for Grafana, but my Java Spring Boot application sends data using Stomp over Websockets, which does not seem possible to send directly.

Options I am leaning towards are:

- Have a service between both (Grafana and Spring Boot) that can process how data is sent from Spring and forward it to Grafana as raw websockets
- I'm looking into Prometheus so it could store data sent from Spring and Grafana could simply query for data from it (avoiding Websockets plugin)

I could refactor the Spring application by removing Stomp and using raw websockets but that option is not so easy because it would require updates in other services that I do not control

I'm just surprised that Stomp can not be used to directly send data to Grafana but hopefully, I'm missing something ??